# How to parse the header values in APIM policy and pass it to the backend API? - Error - input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: c#, azure, api, azure-api-management

I have written below piece of `Policy` to parse the token from the incoming request.

```
<policies>
 <inbound>
   <set-header name="x-request-context-data" exists-action="override">
        <value>@{
            string[] value;
            if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out value))
            {
                if(value != null && value.Length > 0)
                {
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(value[0]));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }</value>
    </set-header>
      <base />
    <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="backend-function" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
      <base />
     </backend>
     <outbound>
     <base />
     </outbound>
     <on-error>
       <base />
     </on-error>
  </policies>
```

Token is generating by Azure AD.

```
   private static IPublicClientApplication _app;
   private static string ClientId = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx";
   private static string Tenant = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx";

   static string[] scopes = new string[]
        {"user.read", "api://xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/clientpoc"};

   var auth = _app.AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode(scopes,
                                        deviceCodeResultCallback =>
                                        { 
                                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                                        })
                                    .ExecuteAsync().Result;

    Console.WriteLine("Token: " + auth.AccessToken);
```

I am initiating the request by passing the `token` using postman

I am getting error shows as below in postman

> Expression evaluation failed. The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it  contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(

Comment: COuld you please provide the steps you use to send and require token?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean you are bypassing the "token" in postman?

Comment: @kudlatiger According to my understanding, your backend api is protected by Azure AD and you want to call the api via APIM. If so, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

Comment: I found a solution. I see that there is no need to manually send token to the backend. it's automatically present in the header, now I feel this question is INVALID.

Comment: @kudlatiger Since you have solved the issue by yourself, could you please post your answer?